# Loop that adds childs in Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've created an XML file that has a list of books,
Now after reading the file, I want to add a movieclip to the stage for every book thats in the list,
I know how to add a child, but I want to name each button differently, like book1_button, book2_button and so on or something,
how do I do that?
 heres the code:

```
function createChilds():void{
    var i:Number = 1;
    //For loop that iterates through all of the books in the XML file
    for each (var bookID:XML in booksList) {

        var bookButton:MovieClip = new book_btn;
        this.addChild(bookButton);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have 'name' property for a MovieClip, right ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that I can think of to approach this problem:

1). Create an `Array` and store all of the book `MovieClip`'s in that `Array`.  How that would be done would look like the following code:

```
var bookArray:Array = [];
function createChilds():void{

    //For loop that iterates through all of the books in the XML file 
    for each (var bookID:XML in booksList) { 

        var bookButton:MovieClip = new book_btn; 
        this.addChild(bookButton); 
        bookArray.push(bookButton);    // Add to the array
    } 
}
```

And then to access a book you would just use `bookArray[1]` or `bookArray[2]` and so on...

2). Name each book something different and use `getChildByName("name")`.  The problem with this is that if you accidently mess up and have two with the same name, you will run into some trouble.  But here is how it would work:

```
function createChilds():void{ 
    var i:Number = 1; 
    //For loop that iterates through all of the books in the XML file 
    for each (var bookID:XML in booksList) { 

        var bookButton:MovieClip = new book_btn; 
        this.addChild(bookButton); 
        bookButton.name = "book"+i.toString();      // Name the book based on i
        i++;                        
    } 
}
```

And then to access each book you would use `getChildByName("book1")`.

Hopefully this helps!  Good luck.

Comment: I would highly suggest the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store the books and then you canaccess the book by array index (e.g bookArray[3]).

```
var bookArray:Array = [];

function createChilds():void{
    var i:Number = 1;
    //For loop that iterates through all of the books in the XML file
    for each (var bookID:XML in booksList) {
        var bookButton:MovieClip = new book_btn;
        this.addChild(bookButton);
        bookArray.push(bookButton);
        i++;
    }
}
```